# Regression formula with log on both sides

Tags: r, regression

I just started to learn about R in class and I need some help with how to translate this equation.

> log(price) = β0 + β1 log(dist) + z

I typed in

```
reg <- lm(lm(price) ~ lm(dist), data = xyz)
```

But it was called an "invalid formula".

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you mean to type `lm` three times? Shouldn't two of them be `log` instead of `lm`?

Comment: I am not sure how to enter 'log' (whether it should be lm or log) into Rstudio :( no the original equation has log twice but I am not sure how it is supposed to appear on the software.

Comment: He meant you should type `reg <- lm(log(price) ~ log(dist), data = xyz)`